# In PHP, test if a cookie has been set

Tags: php, cookies

How can I check if a cookie has been successfully set ?

My try:

```
if(setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 3600 * 24 * 365, '/')) {
    echo 'Cookie created until' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 year') . '.';
}
```

and

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 3600 * 24 * 365, '/');

if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])){
    echo 'Cookie created until' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 year') . '.';
}
```

Both code, did't return me `Cookie created until...`;

Thanks.

Comment: refresh the page and check again... cookies have to be sent to the server

Comment: There might be some output before that, and that could prevent setcookie from returning truthful value.

Comment: @John Conde: where do you see a duplicate here? Sorry but this question if not to check the value but check if the cookie has been create...

Comment: Right, which you are doing *incorrectly*. The duplicate tells you *why* you are checking this incorrectly.

Comment: It's because your miss a `)` into your echo in your first try. It should be `echo 'Cookie created until' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 year')) . '.';`.